# Extracting JSON fields using java

Tags: java, json, facebook

I am trying to extract a person's details who liked a facebook page by passing the page id as parameter. I extracted the JSON content of that page and now from that I want to extract name and id of users.

How do I achieve that ?

### Code:

```
JSONObject json = readurl("https://graph.facebook.com/pageid");
System.out.println(json.toString());
System.out.println("Page id is:"+json.get("id"));
```

### JSON:

```
"likes":{
"data":[
    {
        "id":"*******",
        "name":"vv"
    },
    {
        "id":"********",
        "name":"abc"
    },
```

Comment: Go to json.org and study the JSON syntax.  What you have is very simple.  (Hint: There's no point in converting it back to String, unless you simply want to print that.)

Comment: Note that you omitted the surrounding `{}` characters, which *are* significant -- they're not just `toString` window-dressing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code like this would do the trick.

```
JSONObject json = readurl("https://graph.facebook.com/pageid");
JSONArray dataJsonArray = json.getJSONArray("data");
for(int i=0; i<dataJsonArray.length; i++) {
   JSONObject dataObj = dataJsonArray.get(i);
   String id = dataObj.getString("id");
   //Similarly you can extract for other fields.
}
```

Basically `data` is a JSONArray since it starts with `[`. So simply `get` would not work, you must use JSONArray.

**Note:** I haven't compiled this code, but I think I gave you idea to proceed. Also refer [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/) link to get hold of basics of parsing JSON in java.

Comment: it shows the following exception   Exception in thread "main" facebook4j.internal.org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["data"] not found.
 at facebook4j.internal.org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:464)
 at facebook4j.internal.org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:545)
 at facebook.Fb_rest.main(Fb_rest.java:64)

Comment: inside "likes: is the data field..so Where I have to specift "likes" field

Comment: Are you sure, that json does have `data`?

Comment: Ok, can you post the actual json which you are getting?

Comment: "likes":{"data":[{"id":"********","name":"Aj"},{"id":"******","name":"Ta"},{"id":"*****","name":"Sus"},{"id":"******","name":"Ap"},....this is a part of my o/p ..i can't post the entire o/p since it is extracted from facebook hop u understand

Comment: u can try it on "json parse online" .if u specify fbid of a page through ur graph api it shows o/p..u can test like this

Comment: I tried, it's working fine in my PC, maybe your problem lies elsewhere

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48600/discussion-between-lulu-and-pradeep-simha)

Comment: We need cast (JSONObject) dataJsonArray.get(i)

Answer (score 2):

This snippet is not tested, but I'm pretty sure it works:

```
JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");
for (int i=0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject o = data.getJSONObject(i);
    sysout(o.getString("id");
    sysout(o.getString("name");
}
```

Comment: it shows this exception for your code too  it shows the following exception   Exception in thread "main" facebook4j.internal.org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["data"] not found.
 at facebook4j.internal.org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:464)
 at facebook4j.internal.org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:545)
 at facebook.Fb_rest.main(Fb_rest.java:64)

Comment: inside "likes: is the data field..so Where I have to specift "likes" field.In your code snippet where shall I specify about "likes" tag

Comment: (@smartphone) add `JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("likes");` above my snippet and rename yr `data` variable to `json`.

Comment: i didn't get u...can u explain

Comment: same error..can u explain what u have jst mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I use google's Gson library from: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/