# Java: read single value from Json Document

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to get the value of `num_likes` from a mongodb query.

The code for the query:

```java
FindIterable<Document> comments = postsCollection.find(eq("permalink", permalink))
.projection(fields(exclude(Arrays.asList("body","date", "author", "tags", "title")),slice("comments", ordinal, 1)));

for(Document c: comments) {
    System.out.println(c.get("comments"));
}
```

Output of `println` that shows `num_likes` right at the end:

```
[Document{{author=Tonia Surace, body=Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum, email=DcwPJgyw@mCBzxAfy.com, num_likes=1}}]
```

Not familiar with Java and have tried `c.get("comments").get(0)` without success.

**Update**:

Was able to get the value by destructuring the value one by one. Is there a better way to access it directly?

```
for(Document c: comments) {
    System.out.println(c.get("comments"));
    ArrayList c2 = (ArrayList<Object>) c.get("comments");
    Document d = (Document) c2.get(0);
    System.out.println(d.get("num_likes"));
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting JSON fields using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074192/extracting-json-fields-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB returns json, so you should look for how to extract Json fields in Java ([Extracting JSON fields using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074192/extracting-json-fields-using-java))

You can use any Java json library to have a more convenient access to json fields. Like Jackson or Gson.