# how to get custom data from API in Java

Tags: java, api

Iam using this API -> https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity
So Iam creating a program in Java but when i retrieve data from this above API
like this ->

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class apiTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
String ApiFRomData;
try {
    URL url_name = new URL("https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity");

    BufferedReader sc = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url_name.openStream()));

    // reads public IPAddress
    ApiFRomData = sc.readLine().trim();
    
    
} catch (Exception e) {
    ApiFRomData = "Cannot Execute Properly";
    // return "connection_issue";
}
// return "nothinng";
System.out.println(ApiFRomData);
}
}
```

I get this output in console ->

```
 {
  "activity": "Learn Express.js",
   "accessibility": 0.25,
   "type": "education",
   "participants": 1,
    "price": 0.1,
    "link": "https://expressjs.com/",
   "key": "3943506"
   }
```

but i want a custom output for example...I only want the activity not that {}bracket or that other stuff price, type etc.
I only want the particular custom output
In short how can I get only activity line in output.

please help me :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074192/extracting-json-fields-using-java I think your question was already answered on this thread

Comment: I had just checked that but in that the readurl method is not working and plus all that codes are generating errors.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). That is a format very widely used to transfer data around.
What you need is a [JSON Java Library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json). It can be used to access fields of JSON objects and even turn them into Java Objects.

Here is a small example with the library I referenced above:

```java
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString); // jsonString is what you recieve from your call to the API
// It will be the same as accessing a HashMap [key1 -> value1, key2 -> value2...]

// Now you can access whatever you need from this jsonObject like this:

System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("activity"));
```

Of course you could use your code to do this, but why reinvent the wheel?
Just import this library and you're good to go.